# Byte32 Array is not emitted as array from events

Tags: solidity

I have created this demo [contract](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x4302fd7f3c140a94058ba1214c4f9338f9997e95). It has a function called `convertText` which converts a string text into bytes32 and stores it into `bytes32[] public storedData`.

You can see when you call `convertText()` it emits an event called `SingleEvent` which emits the bytes32 value of the text but when you call `emitEvents()` function it emits a function called `MyEvent` which should emit the array of previous bytes32 value. But here this event doesn't have the first parameter as an array, also it doesn't have the value of byte32 text we saved earlier.

I want to know how can I get the byte32 value of the previous saved byte32 into array from the `MyEvent` event?

Comment: I think you would need to parse the event, check this code snippet https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/156480/104252

Comment: @ZartajAfser It's giving me error that `new ethers.Interface(abi);` is not a constructor

Comment: For understand better your question, in "myEvent" event do you want visualize the last value inserted into array through "convertText" method?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot emit an array automatically in an indexed topic unless you manually loop through its values. This is because an array is a [reference type](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.23/types.html#reference-types), not a value.

From the [Solidity documentation about events](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.23/contracts.html#events):

> [...] A topic can only hold a single word (32 bytes) so if you use a
> reference type for an indexed argument, the Keccak-256 hash of the
> value is stored as a topic instead.

If you want those values automatically, you must remove the `indexed` keyword from your event definition, losing the ability to easily filter those events by their value.

So you should use

```
event MyEvent(bytes32[] data);
```

instead of

```
event MyEvent(bytes32[] indexed data);
```