# Ethers is not decoding the indexed parameters

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I want to get the value from the first indexed parameter of the `TokensTransferred` event from the transaction logs which can look like [this](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x6b244fc1f07e0e2753ee9ebee3c7551a99535f2aa52bcb3add3c5b970e792602#eventlog). You can see that the `TokensTransferred` event has the first indexed parameter as `bytes32[]`. I want to get values from this array.

I tried out this [solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/156453/how-to-fetch-events-emitted-in-a-deployment-transaction-using-ethers-js/156480#156480) but it gave the error that `Interface` is not a constructor. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? How can I get the values from the `bytes32[]` that are emitted from the event in Ethers.js?

I am trying to get the array like this:

```
contract.on('TokensTransferred',(messageId)=>{
        console.log("Message Id: ",messageId);
        const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(fromNetwork?.abi);

        console.log("Decoded Message Ids: ",iface.parseLog([messageId?.hash]));
  }
```

but still this is giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Interface.parseLog
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing an error `Interface is not constructor`, it might be worthwhile to check for any typos or mistakes in the `const iface = new ethers.Interface(abi);` line of the solution (maybe 9th line).
Alternatively, the issue might be due to a change in the specifications of ethers.js because of version differences. [Here](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Interface--creating), it appears to be structured under a hierarchy like this.
`new ethers.utils.Interface(abi);`

Comment: Now I am getting another error, I have added my code snippet with the error above.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the part `iface.parseLog([messageId?.hash])`. The argument for the parseLog() function should be log data, not an array. Similar to the original solution, the data needs to be obtained from transaction receipts or similar sources. For reference on what data to pass as an argument, you might find this [document](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Interface--parsing) or this [source](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/abi/src.ts/interface.ts#L664) helpful.